# pinx 501 with print server - 10 licenses

Tags: print-server

I have pix 501 with only 10 licenses. I'm already approaching this limit, running 2 computers at home, 2 laptops, PS3, iphones, 2 web cams..not everthing is on all the time, but it's possible as I'm looking into adding a print server, so that I can print from anywhere in the house.

So my question is, will the print server count as a connection towards the license? I think it will need default gateway, which in this case will be my pix 501. I've seen somewhere on some othee board saying, don't set default gateway in the print server to pix 501, but then how would that work? is there a work around?
I don't need to print from VPN or from outside, just inside..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are on the same local subnet as the print server, neither of you technically need to have your default-gateway defined.  If you are on different subnets and the firewall will need to route between them, then you need the default gateways.  If you are local, the print server doesn't have to send packets to the PIX501, it already knows where you reside.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no. The print server will not. Also you should understand for future reference that the licensing is for concurrent connections so unless you are using all of the devices at the same time you should be fine.